# php-mysql insert multiple rows from echo radio button

Tags: php, mysql

Actually i want to develop a application from where user can set attendance for student. so the html form for attendance will come from my db query. and it's coming too but the prob is that how can i insert that form information to my db . actually i searched lot but i didn't get any result for this as perfect as i want i mean please can anyone help me . thanks in advance

```
<form action="attendance.php" method="post"> 
<?php include '../database-config.php';
foreach($dbh->query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE active_class='VII'") as $row){
  echo "<div>   
  <label>".htmlentities($row['student_id'])."</label> 
  <input type='radio' name='atten".htmlentities($row['student_id'])."' checked='checked'>Present        
  <input type='radio' name='atten".htmlentities($row['student_id'])."'>Absent
        </div></br>"; 
}
?> 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Submit</button>
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Comment: what are you expecting from :`foreach($dbh->query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE active_class='VII'") as $row){` ??

Comment: You can use a `hidden` field to store the student id or use input arrays.

Comment: actually i don't have good knowledge about php . so can you just provided me any example i mean html multiple radio button to php myqsl multiple data insert . thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="attendance.php" method="post">
    <?php include '../database-config.php';
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE active_class='VII'");
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        ?>
        <div>
         <label><?php echo $row['student_id']?></label>
         <input type="radio" name="attend" value="present" checked>Present
         <input type="radio" name="attend" value="absent">Absent
        </div>
            </br>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Reset</button>
</form>
```

so in php you can get value like this

```
<?php

$attend = $_POST['attend'];

echo $attend;

?>
```

So in `$attend` it contain value(`value="present"`) of radio button.

it may be `present` or either `absent`

Comment: how can i insert into mysql

Comment: `$attend` contain your data. So you can insert that as well

Answer (score 0):

damn getting tired xD
this should work though but you have to add the column attendency to the database table by yourself  cheers

```
   <form action="" method="post">
    <?php

    include '../database-config.php';
    if(isset($_POST['attendency']) && isset($_POST['id']))
    {
        $id_to_update = $_POST['id'];
        $status = $_POST['attendency'];
        $ar = array('p','a');
        $attend = !empty($status) && in_array($status,$ar) ? $status : 'p';


        //you have to create a column named attendency for this to work
        $sql = "INSERT INTO student(attendency)  VALUES ('$attend ') WHERE user_id = '$id_to_update '";
        $dbh->query($sql);
}
    foreach($dbh->query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE active_class='VII'") as $row)
    {

        if($row['attendency'] == 'p')
        {
            $p = 'checked="checked"';
            $a = '';
        } else {
            $a = 'checked="checked"'
     $p = '';
  } ?>

        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$row['student_id']?>">
            <label><?=$row['student_id']?></label>
            <input type='radio' name='attendency' <?=$p?>>Present
            <input type='radio' name='attendency' <?=$a?>>Absent
        </div></br>

    <?php } ?>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Reset</button>
</form>
```